# Highlight the content view of the selected cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

My requirement is to highlight the contentView of the selected cell. As of now the issue is previously selected cell (contentView) is also get highlighted. Code as bellow

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
      cell?.viewWithTag(20)?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
      cell?.viewWithTag(20)?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
   }
```

Comment: This is not a very good way to do highlighting. A cell has a `selectedBackgroundView` that will _automatically_ appear when the cell is selected. It would be much better to use that.

Comment: can u write a code snippet for me to try out

Answer (score 0):

Read up cell reuse. You need to reset your cell's layer in `prepareForReuse`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 3 steps:

1. Go to storyboard and select your cell.
2. In the right panel in Attributes Inspector, change `Selection Style` to `Default`.
3. Also select your tableview and in project Attributes, change `Selection` to `Single Selection`

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain why the above solution wont work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is cell reuse; you need to reset to original state of the cell like so:

```
class HelightTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
}
```

While creating the cell on prepareForReuse change to original state and on did select set the properties like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? HelightTableViewCell {
        return
    }
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do in case using tags instead of custom cell classes

Comment: in that case don't use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath it stop reuse and u can use your old code but that has performance issue like every time new cell it will create

Comment: Hi TheCodeTalker. Stack Overflow is a professional platform, and we would like all posts to be as readable as possible. Abbreviated slang is OK on social media, but not here - please use technical writing as much as you can.